Скачивание вложений из Trello API
Этот код должен скачивать изображение по ссылке. но выходит ошибка 401. При этом полученные ссылки можно открыть, но програмно - нет. В чем может быть дело?
import requests
import os

# URL карточки Trello, откуда берется вложение
url = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{id}/attachments" # здесь я затер личные данные 

# Заголовки запроса
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json"
}

# Параметры запроса с ключом и токеном
query = {
    'key': '', # здесь я затер личные данные 
    'token': '' # здесь я затер личные данные 
}

# Отправка запроса на получение вложений
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=query)

# Проверка успешности запроса
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Разбор JSON-ответа
    attachments = response.json()
    
    # Перебор всех вложений
    for attachment in attachments:
        # Получаем URL изображения
        image_url = attachment.get('url')
        
        if image_url:
            print(f"Загружаем изображение с URL: {image_url}")
            # Получаем имя файла из URL
            image_name = image_url.split('/')[-1]

            # Путь к рабочему столу
            desktop_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop", image_name)

            # Загрузка изображения
            image_response = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)
            
            if image_response.status_code == 200:
                # Сохранение изображения на рабочем столе
                with open(desktop_path, 'wb') as f:
                    for chunk in image_response.iter_content(1024):
                        f.write(chunk)
                print(f"Изображение сохранено: {desktop_path}")
            else:
                print(f"Ошибка при загрузке изображения: {image_response.status_code}")
        else:
            print("Не найден URL для вложения.")
else:
    print(f"Ошибка при получении вложений: {response.status_code}") #Ошибка при загрузке изображения: 401

такой ответ я получаю от сервера
            {
                "_id": "675d33a4b4885cb1361b1362",
                "bytes": 38872,
                "height": 649,
                "id": "675d33a4b4885cb1361b1362",
                "scaled": true,
                "url": "https://trello.com/1/cards.webp", # здесь я затер личные данные 
                "width": 300
            },


а эту строку url = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{id}/attachments" с фигурными скобками внутри вы так и пытаетесь открыть, без подстановки?

@strawdog нет, я просто затер личные данные. я могу получить данные о вложениях в JSON ответе. но что либо сделать с ссылкой не могу. возможно можно преобразовать данные из бинарного кода, но не уверен и пока нет идей как это сделать. сейчас добавлю в код ответ сервера

попробовал через Postman. Результат тот же..

так может, вам нужно так же при получении изображения указывать header и  params? только изменить content-type на "image/webp"?

@strawdog нет, не помогло. mime пробовал в самом начале проб написания кода. Думаете если бы неправильно указывал контент тайп, ошибка была бы 401?

401 - это unauthorized, если я правильно ошибаюсь. значит, вам нужно так же передавать параметры авторизации при запросе, как я и сказал выше.

Также попробовал. Увы, не помогло. Буду еще ковыряться

Вам нужно знать не только ссылку, но и куки, в которых хранится информация об аутентификации. В хроме откройте инструменты разработчика и скопируйте ссылку на скачивание вместе с кукесами.

@PakUula Точно.. спасибо, попробую, дам знать

@PakUula Да, все дело было в куки, смог решить проблему. спасибо большое
